# icCube java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: iccube

I'm trying to build a cube based on a very large dataset and about 15 minutes into the process, I'm getting an: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded  error message. I'm using a trial version of the Enterprise version.

I have 64GB of memory on the machine but the icCube process is only using about 600 MB and I'm not sure how to increase this. I've tried making some changes in the icCube.xml file and restarting the service but none of those changes are having an impact.  Any help would be appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is no auto-expand, you've to define the maximum memory icCube can use on application start (as other Java apps.). You can follow the instruction [here](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/user_guide/configuring_iccube/jre_options.php).

You've another page [here](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/user_guide/configuring_iccube/ram.php) that explains a bit on detail how the memory is used in icCube and different configurations to reduce memory footprint (using memory files for example).